# Can someone tell me why I'm not installing this Django backend correctly?

Tags: python, django, authentication

My project is "fable".  So I created this:

```
/home/myuser/fable/backends/EmailOrUsernameModelBackend.py
```

And also `__init__.py` inside there.

Inside this file, I pasted this snipplet in there:  http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1001/

Now, I change add this to my settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'fable.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)
```

But when I try to login, it says:

```
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /login
Exception Value: Error importing authentication backend fable.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend: "No module named backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Simple spelling mistake in my file.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question or removing it?